# Need to cast to an object without knowing what type the object is

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, casting

I am trying to dynamically load my authentication server type based on a setting.  I am hung up on how to cast to a type when I don't know the type.

```
   Type t = Type.GetType(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AuthenticationSvcImpl"));
    IAuthenticationService authCli = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    return authCli.AuthenticateUser(login);
```

I know there is Convert.ChangeType(), but that just converts to an object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var authCli = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IAuthenticationService;
```

Comment: this did the trick... don't really understand though--why var?

Comment: `var` is just there to save space, else the line was to long, and I was to lazy to split it  :)  `var` == `IAuthenticationService` in this scenario. Basically, your type IS known at compile time, not the actual type, but the compatible interface type.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
Type t = Type.GetType(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AuthenticationSvcImpl"));
IAuthenticationService authCli = (IAuthenticationService) Activator.CreateInstance(t);
return authCli.AuthenticateUser(login);
```